# SQLite access from Ghidra script

Tags: ghidra, java, script

I would like to access an SQLite database from within a Java Ghidra script. However, if I include the line `import java.sql.*;` in the script, Ghidra gives the error `> Unable to locate script class:`. If I understand correctly, only certain Java libraries are available within Ghidra, so is there an SQL library available?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like Ghidra ships with any kind of SQLite library by default, but since Ghidra (I think) 9.2 you can import OSGI compatible .jar files in your scripts. [Supposedly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49514345/13220684) the official SQLite Jar is OSGI compatible already.

The details are explained in the Ghidra Help documents, so for the pretty HTML view: `F1` in Ghidra, `Ghidra Functionality`, `Scripting`, `Ghidra Bundles`[image]

or read the document on some mirror like https://fossies.org/linux/ghidra/Ghidra/Features/Base/src/main/help/help/topics/BundleManager/BundleManager.htm